# Accessing Unknown 'ID' class method-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.h:

```
#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassID)\
enum                                 \
{                                    \
ID = ClassID                         \
};                                   \

@interface RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions : RS232Msg
{

}
@end
```

RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.m

```
@implementation RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions

 DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
@end
```

EventLogs.m

```
-(void)event
{
service = [CServiceAppDlg alloc];
if ([service:(REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID)RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.ID withEvent:pEvent]) 
 {
    NSLog(@"Get Event descriptions!!");
 }
}
```

I'm getting an error like "Accessing Unknown 'ID' class method"
I should not modify the definition here.How to pass the ID.I am going to call different descriptions ID in the same way so is this declaration of ID.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a **Accessing Unknown 'ID' class method** error message is because you have not declared a method called ID in your class `RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions`.

When you say `RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.ID` in your code, you are calling the property `ID` of object `RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions`, which is equivalent to `[RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions ID]`. However, `RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions` is not an object, but a class and you don't have a class method called `+ (REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID)ID` in your class specification (you don't have it declared on the interface or implemented on the class implementation).

I would also like to point out that it is **bad practice** to use the dot notation for something other than a property. Since classes cannot have @properties (these are for objects) you should call this method using standard Objective-C messaging notation `[RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions ID]`.

Xcode will still allow you to write `object.methodName` to call methods with no parameters, and `object.methodName = value` for methods that take 1 parameter. Because they are interpreted as follows:

```
object.methodName;  // Becomes [object methodName]
object.methodName = value;    // Becomes [object setMethodName:value]
```